# To query efficiently in Oracle

Tags: oracle

The Common Log Format is a standardized text file format used by web servers when generating server log files. Example1:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
```

Suppose that an Oracle database is used to store the access log of an e-commerce website with gigabytes of log data over the past six months. Discuss the options we may adopt and the steps involved such that the user can efficiently query all the IP addresses and the files accessed within any given time interval (with specified start time and end time).

Comment: *"Discuss the options we may adopt ..."* Sounds like homework to me

Comment: As with any tuning question you need to define some requirements. How often will you be querying the logs? What's an acceptable response time? What is the most common types of queries you need to support (e.g. find activity for an IP address, list all activity between two date-times, find all hits for a given file). What about housekeeping the logs? Once you can quantity the amount of effort required to query and maintain the raw logs you can figure how much effort to be into optimizing the access. There's no point in expending a lot of effort to make querying efficient if nobody will use it.

Answer (score 1):

If every log entry (such as the one you presented) is stored into one row in an Oracle table, then see if you can split it to store the IP address and date values into **separate columns** (shouldn't be difficult if format is fixed). Then **index** those columns and make access simpler & faster.

If that's not the case, investigate Oracle **Text** capabilities.